# Oracle DataAccess Data provider internal error -3000 when deployed

Tags: odp.net, oracleexception

I'm having an issue with a web service i have created.  It is running fine when running on localhost on my PC.  The problem is, when I deploy the web service to a remote IIS server, I keep getting  "Data provider internal error(-3000)". It always occurs at the OracleConnection.Open portion of the code.  I thought it might be because we have two different "Oracle Home"s on the server, so i tried setting specific home's using the web.config.  Which ever one i choose, i still get the error.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what i can do to solve this?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: I too am having this problem, but on a desktop machine.  Someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help future desperate...
In my case the problem was that ODP versions were different at dev (analyst pc) and production server. Since I couldn't change version at server, I had to force the application to use a specific version defined on config file.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="9.2.0.700" newVersion="9.2.0.700"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.112.3.0" newVersion="9.2.0.700"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. The way I solved it was I changed my reference to a different `Oracle.DataAccess` reference. I was using a version of Oracle client 11.2, and I changed it to 12.2; that solved the problem.